# XUL box inside position: fixed element won't align center

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

The `#LoginOuterBox` `hbox` is about half the width of `#FullScreenLoginWrapper`, but is docked to the left side of the screen. It is refusing to obey `pack="center"` or `align="center"` on the parent.

```
<vbox id="browser-panel">
   <hbox id="FullScreenLoginWrapper" pack="center"  flex="1">
      <hbox id="LoginOuterBox" pack="start" >         
         <vbox flex="1">
            <label class="header" value="Welcome"/>
            <hbox class="FieldWrapper">
               <vbox pack="center">
                  <label value="Username" class="FieldLabel" control="LoginUsername"/>
               </vbox>
               <textbox id="LoginUserName" />
            </hbox>
            <hbox class="FieldWrapper">
               <vbox pack="center">
                  <label value="Password" class="FieldLabel" control="LoginPassword"/>
               </vbox>
               <textbox type="password" id="LoginPassword" />
            </hbox>
            <hbox  class="FieldWrapper" align="right">
               <button label="Login" class="ATKButton"/>
            </hbox>
         </vbox>
         <vbox align="center" width="300px;">
            <hbox pack="center">
               <image src='chrome://myaddon/skin/swim.svg' width='200px' />
            </hbox>
         </vbox>
      </hbox>
   </hbox>
</vbox>
```

Corresponding styles:

```
#FullScreenLoginWrapper{
   position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   right:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   z-index:2000;
   background:#272727;   
   color:#ccc;
}

#LoginOuterBox{
   border:1px solid #222;
   background:linear-gradient(#272727, #222222);
   padding:20px;
   margin:20px auto;
   border-radius:5px;

}

#FullScreenLoginWrapper label.header{
   margin-bottom:22px;
   font-size:22px;
   font-weight:normal;
   text-align:right;
}



#FullScreenLoginWrapper .FieldWrapper{
   margin-bottom:7px;
}

#FullScreenLoginWrapper textbox{
   width:200px;
}


#FullScreenLoginWrapper label.FieldLabel{
   width:95px;
   text-align:right;
   font-size:12px;
   margin-right:15px;
}

.ATKButton {
    background: linear-gradient(#333333, #222222) no-repeat scroll 1px 1px #494849;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 28px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 120px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

What I want is the equivalent of:

```
div{
margin:0px auto;
width:50%;
}
```

where the box is centered in the parent (on the screen). How do I achieve this?

Comment: How is it half width? Do you have some CSS or...? Please post a more complete example.

Comment: It's about half width based on the contents inside it. I have tried explicitly setting it to 50% using CSS, but it made no difference in alignment.

Comment: It very likely is not. `style="border: 1px solid red;"` to see what I mean.

Comment: I have a red border on it, it's about half the size of the screen, stuck to the left.

Comment: That's... unexpected. I need a complete example I can use to reproduce.

Comment: I've added the full XUL and CSS above.

Comment: And what element is supposed to be centered now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: fixed` in XUL is nasty and does not really behave correctly.

You need to work around this by wrapping `#LoginOuterBox` in an additional:

```
<hbox style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" pack="center" align="center">
```

Also, since it seems this is meant to overlay `browser.xul`, please choose your DOM ids and class names wisely, so that their won't conflict with the browser or other add-ons nor or in the future. Usually you do this via a fake-namespace, by prefixing everything with `myveryuniqueaddonid-someid`.